# Tab bottom navigation react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-native-tabnavigator

I new in react-native and junior developer.
I'm using **react-native v0.70.6**

**@react-navigation/stack** and **@react-navigation/bottom-tabs**.

My tab bottom component looks like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
                initialRouteName='Home'
                screenOptions={{
                    headerShown:false, 
                    tabBarShowLabel:false,
                    tabBarStyle:style.tabsBottomContainer
                }}
                sceneContainerStyle={style.backgroundContent}
                >
                   <Tab.Screen 
                    name='Assets'
                    component={AssetScreen}
                    options={{unmountOnBlur:true,tabBarIcon:({focused,color})=>(
                        <View>
                           <Image
                                source={iconAsset}
                                style={{
                                    tintColor: focused ? '#00B2DF' : '',
                                    marginTop: 8
                                }}
                                />
                        </View>
                    )}}
                    />
                   <Tab.Screen 
                    name='Bluetooth'
                    component={ConnectScreen}
                    children = {()=> <NotFoundGateway />}
                    options={{unmountOnBlur:true,tabBarIcon:({focused,color})=>(
                        <View>
                           <Image
                                source={iconBluetooth}
                                style={{
                                    tintColor: focused ? '#00B2DF' : ''
                                }}
                                />
                        </View>
                    )}}
                    />
                    <Tab.Screen 
                        name='Home'
                        component={HomeScreen}
                        options={{unmountOnBlur:true,tabBarIcon:({focused,color})=>(
                            <View>
                               <Image
                                    source={iconHome}
                                    style={{
                                        tintColor: focused ? '#00B2DF' : ''
                                    }}
                                    />
                            </View>
                        )}}
                    />
            </Tab.Navigator>
```

Inside **index.tsx** I have a navigation that does not need the bottom tabs. For example the Login. -->

```
<NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='tabsBottomHome'>
          {state.isSignIn ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
              name='tabsBottomHome'
              component={TabsBottomHome}
              options={headerOptions}
              />
              ):(
               <Stack.Screen
                name="Login"
                component={LoginScreen}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="LoginError"
                component={LoginError}
                options={headerOptions}
              />
             )
            </>
          )}
</Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

The components between the bottom tabs are displayed perfectly. But since I add secondary components to my navigation. For example, I enter the Bluetooth component, within that component I have to enter another component, without losing the bottom tabs.

What would be the correct way to do it?
And how could I set all the routes inside my tabs bottom component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
I had to change my navigation structure as follows :
my main structure is like this-->

```
   <NavigationContainer>
                    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='tabsBottomHome'
                      screenOptions={{
                        headerTitle: () => <Header />,
                        headerBackground: () => <HeaderBackground />,
                        headerLeft: ({ onPress, canGoBack }) =>
                          canGoBack ? (
                            <Pressable onPress={onPress} style={{ width: 30, height: 15 }}>
                              <ArrowLeft height={15} width={15} style={{ marginLeft: 15 }} />
                            </Pressable>
                          ) : (
                            <Pressable style={{ width: 65, height: 35 }}></Pressable>
                          ),
                        headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
                      }}
                    >
                      {state.isSignIn ? (
                        <>
                          <Stack.Screen
                          name='tabsBottomHome'
                          component={TabsBottomHome}
                          options={{headerShown: false }}
                          />
                        </>
                      ) : (
                        <>
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="Login"
                            component={LoginScreen}
                            options={{ headerShown: false }}
                          />
                          <Stack.Screen
                            name="LoginError"
                            component={LoginError}
                          />
                        </>
                      )}
                    </Stack.Navigator>
                  </NavigationContainer>
```

my **tab bottom navigation** structure looks like this

```
  <Tab.Navigator
                    initialRouteName='Home'
                    screenOptions={{
                        headerShown:true, 
                        tabBarShowLabel:false,
                        tabBarStyle:style.tabsBottomContainer,
                        unmountOnBlur: true,
                        headerTitle: () => <Header />,
                        headerBackground: () => <HeaderBackground />,
                        headerLeft: () =>
                            routeName != "Home" ? (
                                <Pressable onPress={navigateBack} style={{ width: 65, height: 15 }}>
                                  <ArrowLeft height={15} width={15} style={{ marginLeft: 15 }} />
                                </Pressable>
                            ) 
                            : (
                                <Pressable style={{ width: 65, height: 35 }}></Pressable>
                            )
                          ,
                        headerRight: () => <HeaderRight />,
                    }}
                    sceneContainerStyle={style.backgroundContent}
                    screenListeners={({route})=>({
                        state: ()=> {
                            setRouteName(route.name);
                        }
                      })}
                    backBehavior={'history'}
                    >
                       <Tab.Screen 
                        name='Assets'
                        component={AssetScreen}
                        options={{tabBarIcon:({focused,color})=>(
                            <View>
                               <Image
                                source={iconAsset}
                                style={{
                                    tintColor: focused ? '#00B2DF' : '',
                                    marginTop: 8
                                }}
                                    />
                            </View>
                        )}} />
                       <Tab.Screen 
                        name='GatewayStack'
                        component={ConnectGatewayStack}
                        options={{tabBarIcon:({focused,color})=>(
                            <View>
                               <Image
                                source={iconBluetooth}
                                style={{
                                    tintColor: focused ? '#00B2DF' : ''
                                }}
                                    />
                            </View>
             )}} />
    
           </Tab.Navigator>
```

And my **ConnectGatawayStack** structure contains the navigation of all that Tab, therefore it is inside my Tab and the focus is not lost and it works correctly. Obviously now I am facing a goBack problem. but that's another kind of problem.

**ConnectGatawayStack** -->

```
  export type StackConnectList = {
        Connect: undefined;
        QRScan: undefined;
        GatewayList: undefined;
        GatewayInfo: undefined;
        NotFoundGateway: undefined;
        GatewayDetected: undefined;
        ErrorConnecting: undefined;
    }
    
    const GatewayStack =  createStackNavigator<StackConnectList>();
    const ConnectGatewayStack = ()  =>{
        return (
        <GatewayStack.Navigator  initialRouteName='Connect'
         screenOptions={{headerShown:false}}
         >
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='Connect' component={ConnectScreen} /> 
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='GatewayList' component={GatewayList} />
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='GatewayInfo' component={GatewayInfo} />
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='QRScan' component={QRScanScreen} />
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='NotFoundGateway' component={NotFoundGateway} />
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='GatewayDetected' component={GatewayDetected} />
            <GatewayStack.Screen name='ErrorConnecting' component={ErrorConnecting} />
        </GatewayStack.Navigator>
        )
    }
    
    export  {ConnectGatewayStack};
```

Thanks!